# AWS Cognito - offline data availability

Tags: javascript, cordova, amazon-web-services, offline, amazon-cognito

I am building a phonegap app and use AWS Cognito to store the User data. In the description of Cognito, it is said, that the data is offline available. This does not work in my code:

```
var add_data;    
function getCognitoData(){
 var params = {
  IdentityPoolId: COGNITO_IDENTITY_POOL_ID,
  Logins: {
   'graph.facebook.com': FACEBOOK_TOKEN
  }  
 };
 AWS.config.region = AWS_REGION;
 AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);
 AWS.config.credentials.get(function(err) {
  if (err) {
   console.log("Error: "+err);
   return;
  }
  console.log("Cognito Identity Id: " + AWS.config.credentials.identityId);

  var syncClient = new AWS.CognitoSyncManager();

  syncClient.openOrCreateDataset('myDataset', function(err, dataset) {
   dataset.get('myKey', function(err, value) {
    console.log(value, err);
   });

   add_data = function(thisid, thisval) {
    dataset.put(thisid, thisval, function(err, record){
     dataset.synchronize({
      onSuccess: function(data, newRecords) {
       console.log("success", newRecords);
      },
      onFailure: function(err) {
       console.log("error", err);
      },
      onConflict: function(dataset, conflicts, callback) {
       console.log("sync conflict", dataset, conflicts);
       var resolved = [];

       for (var i=0; i<conflicts.length; i++) {
        resolved.push(conflicts[i].resolveWithRemoteRecord());
       }

       dataset.resolve(resolved, function() {
        return callback(true);
       });
      }
     });
    });
   }
  });
 });
}
```

The AWS Credentials for the Identity Pool and the Facebook Token are previously set, and work in the online mode, but I don't get the dataset data, when being offline.

Am I doing something wrong or is it generally not possible to get the Cognito Dataset data while being offline? I read, that the data is actually being held in the local storage.

I am using the current AWS SKD (Release v2.1.42) and the Amazon Cognito JS.

Comment: did you ever figure out a solution for this? I'm running into the same issue...

Comment: Has this been working for you since the bug fix? https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js/issues/17

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get the data offline. You need to [synchronize](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/devguide/sync/synchronizing-data/) the dataset to get whatever contents may be inside, otherwise them being empty is expected. Are you doing that? If not, try doing that, but if so, can you update your code above?

Comment: Hi Jeff, thank your for your quick answer! I included the part where I add the data. I call the synchronize on the dataset, right after adding data, but still no data is offline available.

Comment: Hmm...the put call is what writes it to the local cache. Have you checked the err in the put call?

Comment: It seems, that the IdentityId is lost while being offline and a new is assigned as soon as the user goes online.

Other people are having the same issue:
https://github.com/aws/amazon-cognito-js/issues/17

Comment: Why would you need to Sync the dataset in the "offline" scenario? By definition, if the app is offline it wouldn't even be able to sync back to the Cognito Cloud.

Comment: To clarify - you need to synchronize when online to get the data locally and have access to it while offline.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug with the `aws-sdk-js` causing the offline bug. CognitoSync depends on `aws-sdk-js`. Should be working now as of `aws-sdk-js@2.7.21`. Make sure you update.